# Grid isn't responsive in Chrome and Safari (stuck at 980px window-width)

Tags: responsive-design, css-grid, window-resize

**The problem is:** when changing width of a window in Chrome or Safari, my grid element would create 1 additional row to fit its children, and when the window is shrunk even further it won't create any more rows, it keeps just 2 rows and, instead, begins to resize itself ([pic.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXS0L.png)).

It's the first time I see this problem and, honestly, can't understand what I'm missing there.

I've tested **the same HTML file in Firefox** -- and it works how intended ([pic.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTFwo.png)). The grid works just fine, creating as many rows as it needs to fit all its children. I have replicated the same styles and structure in CodePen, and it works fine on CodePen page in Chrome ([pic.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJEe8.png)), but if I download my CodePen project and open it in Chrome or Safari like an HTML file -- it has the same problem ([pic.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXS0L.png)).

I'd appreciate any suggestion or a correction. Thanks for your time.

*CodePen link:* https://codepen.io/vkharlakov/pen/wvjEgWM

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section>
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
          <li>4</li>
          <li>5</li>
          <li>6</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: plum;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 250px);
    grid-auto-rows: 350px;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 3px solid steelblue;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your Example works for me in chrome as you aspect it to do. Maybe an older version still is in cache.

Comment: @Schulze thanks for the suggestion. I've cleared cache and the issue remains :( I've also tested opening this file in Safari and Chrome on other devices and all of them show the same picture..

Comment: Ahh sorry - I didnt see, that the mistake took place in this responsibility Module. I'll have a look

Comment: When I use the inspector, it says a much higher width as possible. Would bet, that it is a Chrome failure. But when resizing the window manually u can archieve the desired behavior.

Comment: @Schulze I was hoping that it was just the Chrome's devtools bug, but Safari also showed the same issue.. what interesting is that if I disable touch simulator in Firefox's devtools and resize the window - it'll be as responsive as I want it to be, but if I turn this touch simulator on - then it stops working again

Comment: Have you tried to display that site on a real phone?

Comment: @Schulze I have: on iPhone 7 plus and iPhone 12 - both showed the same picture. Thanks for sticking with me on this, I'm kinda frustrated by this bug

Comment: NP. I tried to look at the Window size by writing it realtime into the console. somehow it's stuck at 980. Even though there is an actual width of 700 or less. Gonna investigate further on this.

Comment: @Schulze thanks to you I found a solution :) You gave me a hint with 980px on how to google my issue, and I found a decent amount of suggestions to include a standard meta tag about which I somehow forgot: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />. It fixed the problem.

Comment: Nice that I was able to help. That nut was too hard to crack for me at the moment. But yeah I know that meta tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you found yourself searching the Internet with the same question, consider including this meta tag in your `<head></head>` section of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

It fixed the issue for me. Hope it helps you too!